# Apple Mail constantly prompts for Exchange password of defunct e-mail address

Tags: macos, apple-mail

I have setup a university issued Microsoft Exchange e-mail address in my Internet Accounts on MacOS 12.6.3. Once I left the institution, this e-mail address is no longer active. Since I want to keep my e-mails in Mail, I have archived all messages, i.e., I clicked on "Archive" in the contextual menu when all e-mails in the Inbox were selected, and took the account offline.

However, I keep getting the annoying prompt

```
Exchange Password Required
Enter your password for "[e-mail address]" in Internet Accounts.
```

How can I permanently retire the mailbox in Mail such that this prompt does not constantly show up?

I am aware that I could export the mailbox and archive it on my file system. However, I would loose the ability to search for old e-mails which is important to me.

Comment: In this [post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251202049) the solution was: Go to Mail -> Preferences -> selected the exchange account -> server settings -> uncheck "automatically manage connection settings". Does it help?

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't do the trick, the notification keeps showing up

Comment: I don't have your environment, but can't you mutilate the account enough that it won't ask for the password, for example by leaving blank the domain name of the Exchange server.

Comment: it appears that a blank/invalid field is not accepted and will be auto-filled

Comment: What about a wrong address? I note that in my search over the internet I haven't found any advertised solution to this problem.

Comment: Mail would not accept a wrong entry. Searching on several boards, I got the impression that this is a common frustration with Mac.

Comment: What happens if you block the server site in the firewall ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found out that this happens because of the incompatibility between Apple's mail app and Microsoft Account's MFA. I've solved this by using App Passwords https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/using-app-passwords-with-apps-that-don-t-support-two-step-verification-5896ed9b-4263-e681-128a-a6f2979a7944, see if that helps!